# Excel 2010 VBA - Storing decimal in array and using to chart percentage of stored value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

SO Community,

I'm looking to automate some of the metrics that are used at my work using VBA. I am currently trying to read through an array that I have my ticketing raw data stored in and then either store the value as a decimal or percentage. After this is stored in the array, I am attempting to create or update a chart series with the array and display this value as a percent. I suspect that I'm just missing some syntax for this, but I have checked SO, MSDN and Excel help and have had no luck. I have attached the relevant code below:

**FUNCTION**

```
Function calcTopApplications(iArray As Variant)

Dim m_counter As Long, r_counter As Long, placeholder As Double
Dim fNav_counter As Long, pmoNav_counter As Long, rmgr_counter As Long, wlm_counter As Long, total_counter As Long
ReDim tkt_month_arr(12), tkt_fnav_arr(12)

For m_counter = 1 To 12
    fNav_counter = 0
    pmoNav_counter = 0
    rmgr_counter = 0
    wlm_counter = 0
    total_counter = 0
    For r_counter = 2 To UBound(iArray, 1)
        If iArray(r_counter, 1) <> iArray(r_counter - 1, 1) Then
            If CDate(iArray(r_counter, 5)) >= DateAdd("m", -m_counter, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)) Then
                If CDate(iArray(r_counter, 5)) < DateAdd("m", (1 - m_counter), DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)) Then
                total_counter = total_counter + 1
                    If StrConv(iArray(r_counter, 7), vbLowerCase) = "franchise navigator" Then
                        fNav_counter = fNav_counter + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r_counter
    placeholder = FormatNumber(fNav_counter / total_counter, 2)
    tkt_month_arr(12 - (m_counter - 1)) = CLng(DateAdd("m", -m_counter, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)))
    tkt_fnav_arr(12 - (m_counter - 1)) = placeholder
Next m_counter

End Function
```

**SUBROUTINE**

```
If Me.ChartObjects("Top 4 Applications Ticket Volume") Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Me.Shapes.AddChart
        .Left = Me.Range("A16").Left
        .Top = Me.Range("A16").Top
        .Width = Me.Range("A16:S16").Width
        .Height = Me.Range("A16:A30").Height
        .Select
    End With
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .ChartStyle = 42
        .HasDataTable = True
        .HasTitle = True
        .Parent.Name = "Top 4 Applications Ticket Volume"
        .ChartTitle.Caption = "Open/Close Ticket Volume by Month (Top 4 Applications)"
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        .NewSeries
        .Item(1).Name = "Franchise Navigator"
        .Item(1).XValues = tkt_month_arr
        .Item(1).Values = tkt_fnav_arr
    End With
Else
    With Me.ChartObjects("Top 4 Applications Ticket Volume")
        .Select
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        .Item(1).XValues = tkt_month_arr
        .Item(1).Values = tkt_fnav_arr
    End With
End If
```

This gives me the values for the percentage but does not behave on the chart as a percentage (have the % symbol).

Comment: I think you are asking: "if I have computed percentages, how do I make them show on my chart as percentages?". If so - consider greatly simplifying your example code, and try to set the formatting of the chart to percentage (hint: formatting the axis is usually how you do that). Try doing it manually and record your actions as a macro: I think you will be able to figure it out from there. If you can't, show your "best effort" and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: When I manually select percentage for the y axis, the major tick labels update and the data points are in the correct position. However, the data table continues to show the values as decimal (0.45, 0.02, etc.) I don't think I can record a macro in this case since manually changing the axis to percentage doesn't correct the issue and the data is coming from my array but please let me know if I'm mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: Ooooh - I see the problem. Very interesting, and not immediately obvious how to fix this. When you create a chart "normally" and add a data table, all you have to do is format the source cells, and the table follows. But the method you use means you don't have "source cells" - right? One "ugly workaround" would be to create a hidden sheet, and put the data there, and format it correctly. I hope there's a better way though. I will think about it.

Comment: While it wasn't the route I wanted to go with it, storing the values in a hidden workbook and then pointing my chart to that range worked. While I think it would be great if Microsoft Excel allowed us to change the datatypes of a data table, I can live with this workaround for now. Thanks for all of your help Floris!

Comment: Converted my suggestion to an "answer" - that way the next person with the same question will not have to read all the comments. And you could even mark it as "accepted"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a chart "normally" and add a data table, all you have to do is format the source cells, and the table follows. But the method you use means you don't have "source cells"; and as far as I was able to tell, Microsoft doesn't provide a method to modify the formatting of the data table when it's generated with your method.

An "ugly workaround" is to create a hidden sheet, put the data there, and format it correctly. Point to this data when you create the data table, and the formatting will be correct.

It would be nice if Microsoft provided the flexibility you are asking for... *sigh*